# Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

i deplyed my application on kubernetes but have been getting this error:

```
**MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "airflow-volume" : mount failed: mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a3c3d0b-b7e8-49bc-8a78-5a8bdc932eca/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/airflow-volume --scope -- mount -t glusterfs -o auto_unmount,backup-volfile-servers=10.0.2.107:10.0.2.24,log-file=/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/glusterfs/airflow-volume/worker-844c9db787-vprt8-glusterfs.log,log-level=ERROR 10.0.2.107:/airflow /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a3c3d0b-b7e8-49bc-8a78-5a8bdc932eca/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/airflow-volume Output: Running scope as unit run-22059.scope. mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a3c3d0b-b7e8-49bc-8a78-5a8bdc932eca/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/airflow-volume: unknown filesystem type 'glusterfs'. , the following error information was pulled from the glusterfs log to help diagnose this issue: could not open log file for pod worker-844c9db787-vprt8**
```

AND

```
**Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[airflow-volume], unattached volumes=[airflow-volume default-token-s6pvd]: timed out waiting for the condition**
```

Any suggestions?

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: airflow
        tier: web
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: peeriqregistrykey
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        # Airflow Webserver Container
        - name: web
          image: peeriq/data_availability_service:airflow-metadata-cutover
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow
              name: airflow-volume
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: airflow-config
          env:
            - name: VAULT_ADDR
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: vault-credentials
                  key: VAULT_ADDR
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: vault-credentials
                  key: VAULT_TOKEN
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
            - name: FERNET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: airflow-secrets
                  key: FERNET_KEY
            - name: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 8080
          args: ["webserver"]
        # Airflow Scheduler Container
        - name: scheduler
          image: peeriq/data_availability_service:airflow-metadata-cutover
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow
              name: airflow-volume
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: airflow-config
          env:
            - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              value: us-east-1
            - name: ETL_AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: aws-creds
                  key: ETL_AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
            - name: VAULT_ADDR
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: vault-credentials
                  key: VAULT_ADDR
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: vault-credentials
                  key: VAULT_TOKEN
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
            - name: FERNET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: airflow-secrets
                  key: FERNET_KEY
            - name: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          args: ["scheduler"]
      volumes:
        - name: airflow-volume
          # This GlusterFS volume must already exist.
          glusterfs:
            endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
            path: /airflow
            readOnly: false
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flower
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: flower
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: airflow
        tier: flower
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: peeriqregistrykey
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: flower
          image: peeriq/data_availability_service:airflow-metadata-cutover
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow
              name: airflow-volume
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: airflow-config
          env:
            # To prevent the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tcp://10.0.0.83:5555'
            - name: FLOWER_PORT
              value: "5555"
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
            - name: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          ports:
            - name: flower
              containerPort: 5555
          args: ["flower"]
      volumes:
        - name: airflow-volume
          # This GlusterFS volume must already exist.
          glusterfs:
            endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
            path: /airflow
            readOnly: false
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: worker
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: airflow
        tier: worker
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: peeriqregistrykey
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: worker
          image: peeriq/data_availability_service:airflow-metadata-cutover
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/airflow
              name: airflow-volume
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: airflow-config
          env:
            - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              value: us-east-1
            - name: ETL_AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: aws-creds
                  key: ETL_AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
            - name: VAULT_ADDR
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: vault-credentials
                  key: VAULT_ADDR
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: vault-credentials
                  key: VAULT_TOKEN
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_USER
            - name: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: django-auth
                  key: DJANGO_AUTH_PASS
            - name: FERNET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: airflow-secrets
                  key: FERNET_KEY
            - name: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: rds-postgres
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          args: ["worker"]
      volumes:
        - name: airflow-volume
          # This GlusterFS volume must already exist.
          glusterfs:
            endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
            path: /airflow
            readOnly: false
```

Comment: Have you installed GlusterFS on your cluster?
Check this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#glusterfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install package `glusterfs-fuse` on your Kubernetes nodes, otherwise it won't be able to mount glusterfs volumes.

Comment: Hey @vasili is glusterfs-fuse for ubuntu? and if not, is there anything recommended for ubuntu?

Comment: Read more here: https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator-Guide/Setting-Up-Clients/

Answer (score 0):

The part of the message `unknown filesystem type 'glusterfs'` can mean that there is something wrong with your volume definition or a storage class if you use it. But this is a guess.

Comment: but this has been working on prod env. i tried it on test env. the difference is test env k8s is on EKS. this shouldnt make difference but this has been working for prod.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and the reason in my kubernetes was that the nfs server was unavailable. After starting the nfs server, it was solved.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30303045)